# 1-bit and 2-bit Characters

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

We have two special characters. The first character can be represented by one bit 0. The second character can be represented by two bits (10 or 11).

Now given a string represented by several bits. Return whether the last character must be a one-bit character or not. The given string will always end with a zero.

Example 1:
Input: 
bits = [1, 0, 0]
Output: True

Input: 
bits = [1, 1, 1, 0]
Output: False

```
class Solution {
public boolean isOneBitCharacter(int[] bits) {
    int n = bits.length-1;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=n;i<=n;i--){
        if(bits[i]==1){
            count++;
        }else break;

    }return count%2==0;
}
}
```

this code is not working for some test cases
my 2nd example test case is not working

Comment: `for(int i=n;i>0;i++)` Isn't it an infinite loop?

Comment: now.............?

Comment: Think about your `return` statement. What it is checking? Is `4` a result that should return `true`?

Comment: Now the stop condition is identical to the variable assignment, `i = n`. The loop won't run. Please post working code.

Comment: "If this bit is `1`, increment `count`, otherwise break out of the loop" sounds a bit fishy.

Comment: i want to count 1 if it is odd no. then i will return false i will start counting from 2nd last int of array upto 1st index for example in 1,1,1,0 the no. of 1 is 3 and length is 4 so lost character have to be 2 bit

Comment: can i get the right code with this method

Comment: @NaveenVerma I added C++ example

Comment: @Guy `for(int i=n;i>0;i++)` is not an infinite loop. `i` will wrap around to a negative number once it reaches `MAX_INT` (basically, 2^31). So it's not an *infinite* loop. A pretty long one, though, and likely not what he wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For long bitstreams would be much faster to investigate the bit-stream from the end... However its a bit more harder to detect the cases. When we look at the ending bits:

```
.....00 // 1 bit
.....01 // error
.....10 // 1/2 bit
.....11 // 2 bit
```

we can determine answer right away unless the `.....10` case is present in which case we need to investigate one more bit:

```
....110 // 1/2 bit
....010 // 2 bit
```

and again:

```
....1110 // 1/2 bit
....0110 // 1 bit
```

and again:

```
...11110 // 1/2 bit
...01110 // 2 bit
```

As you can see the consequent ones count determine if the last word is 1 or 2 bit (it is alternating) for odd count its 1 and for even its 2 bit word.

So simply detect which case it is and throw answe right away or count consequent ones before last zero and determine answer from that.

This way you do not need to process whole stream just the end until zero is encountered.

So:

```
.....11 // 2 bit or error
.....01 // error
.....00 // 1 bit
....010 // 2 bit
...0110 // 1 bit
..01110 // 2 bit
.011110 // 1 bit
0111110 // 2 bit
```

only in case you hit the start of stream (no zero at start) its needed to process whole array but that is improbable ... as its just a single case where the stream look like this:

```
111.....111X
```

so no or just single zero at the end but the count of ones before last bit will still tell you if the ending is 1 or 2 bits long... for that you can do:

```
last_word_bit_length= 1 + (consequent_ones_count&1)
```

I do not code in JAVA so here a C++ example instead (should not be hard to port it):

```cpp
int last_word_bits(int *bits,int n)
    {
    int i=0;
    if (n<1) return 0;                      // empty
    if (n>=1) i|=bits[n-1];
    if (n>=2) i|=bits[n-2]<<1;
    if (i==1) return 0;                     // ...00 or ...0 -> error
    if (i==0) return 1;                     // ...01 -> 1
    if (i==3) return 2;                     // ...11 -> 2 or error
    // count consequent ones
    for (i=0,n-=2;n>=0;n--,i++)
     if (bits[n]==0) break;
    return 1+(i&1);
    }
```

giving answers:

```
{1,0,0} -> 1
{1,1,1,0} -> 2
```

I am expecting bitstream does not contain errors otherwise the special case `i==3` need to count the ones too... to determine if it is error or not

Comment: Nice. This actually looks like what the OP was trying to do in their original attempt - counting consecutive 1s near the end of the array (though the OP had some errors).

Comment: @Eran yep I saw the loop ... I taught at first its enough to investigate just last 2 or 3 bits but the special case need a loop too...

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
public boolean isOneBitCharacter(int[] bits) {
    int n = bits.length - 1;
    int count = 0;
    while (count < n) {
        count += bits[count] + 1;
    }
    return count == n;
}
```

**Explanation:**

You start reading from left to right, if you encounter `bits[i] == 0`, it means that the next character will have 1 bit. And if `bits[i] == 1` it means that the next character will have 2 bits. You keep incrementing the `count` to the start of each next character. In the end, if `count` is equals to `n`, it would mean that the last character is 1 bit.

Comment: Interesting solution, though less intuitive.

Comment: Thanks, @Eran for the appreciation. I agree that it isn't very intuitive, but it does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Given all the issues with your loop (before and after your edit), it's hard to say which code you actually tried.

Either way, your logic is wrong. You have to iterate over the "bits" the `String` from left to right, and keep some state variables that tell you if the last character encountered was a 1-bit or 2-bit character.

For example:

```
boolean started2bit = false;
boolean last1bit = false;
for(int i=0;i<bits.length;i++) {
    if (started2bit) { // previous bit was the start of a 2-bit character and current
                       // bit (either 1 or 0) ends that character
        started2bit = false;
        last1bit = false;
    } else if (bits[i]==1) { // 1 starts a 2-bit character
        started2bit = true;
        last1bit = false;
    } else { // current bit is 0, and it represents a 1-bit character
        last1bit = true;
    }
}
return last1bit; // the last character we read was a 1-bit character
```

Or, even simpler, as Hans suggested:

```
boolean last1bit = false;
for(int i=0;i<bits.length;i++) {
    if (bits[i]==1) { // 1 starts a 2-bit character
        i++; // the next bit finishes a 2-bit character, so we can skip it
        last1bit = false;
    } else { // current bit is 0, and it represents a 1-bit character
        last1bit = true;
    }
}
return last1bit; // the last character we read was a 1-bit character
```

Comment: if you find the start of a 2-bit character, you can skip the next index (`i++`) - saves one state variable

Comment: @NaveenVerma why not?

Comment: @NaveenVerma I tried the 2 sample inputs you mentioned and got true for the first and false for the second.

Comment: @NaveenVerma Oh, I see the source of the confusion. Your `n` variable contains `bits.length - 1`, so if you use it in the loop, it should be `i<=n`. I replaced it with `i<bits.length` to avoid the confusion.

Comment: have you tried on leetcode ? it is returning false for first , dont know why

Answer (score 0):

Python3 code based on @Spektre 's solution above. Any suggestions to improve the code are welcome.

```
class Solution:
    def isOneBitCharacter(self, bits: List[int]) -> bool:
        # if it's only 1 bit
        if len(bits) == 1:
            if bits[0] == 0:
                return True
            else:
                # throwInvalidInputException
                return False
        
        # if it ends in 1 then error
        if bits[-1] == 1:
            # throwInvalidInputException
            return False
        
        # if it ends in 00 then True
        if bits[-2:] == [0, 0]:
            return True
        
        # if it ends in 10 then ??
        if bits[-2:] == [1, 0]:
            i = len(bits)
            while i > 0:
                i -= 1
                if bits[i-1:i+1] == [0, 1]: break

            # in case the loop completes - need to check the first character
            if bits[i-1] == 1: i -= 1
                
            # i is now pointing to the first 1 in ....11110
            if len(bits[i:]) % 2 == 1:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

This will help understand the 'ending in 10' case:

```
"""
    Assuming no invalid input is received.
F   10

F   010
T   110

F   0010
T   0110
F   1010
F   1110

    111111110 - len odd True
    11111110 - len even false
"""
```